# css js slider that can be used multiple times on a single page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I would like to make CSS/jQuery slider that can be used multiple times on the same HTML page.

I have a customer that needs sliders as category links. So far I didn't manage to get it working as single slider on a page. Can someone check the code and point out what I am doing wrong? I don't know how to organize the project.

If someone can just write down the steps to take, I don't need code, how would this be done most efficiently I would really appreciate it.

```js
var intervalid = {};

$(document).ready(function() {

  function slide(elem) {
    sliderid = $("#" + elem);
    //console.log(sliderid);

    //console.log(sliderid.find(".main_image"));

    sliderid.find(".main_image").on("mouseover", function() {
      //alert("hover");
      $(this).find(".main-desc").css("display", "block");
    });

    sliderid.find(".main_image").on("mouseleave", function() {
      //alert("hover");
      $(this).find(".main-desc").css("display", "none");
    });

    intervalid[elem] = setInterval(slidecycle(elem), 4500);
    //myinter = setInterval(testcycle(elem), 4500);
    //console.log(intervalid);
  }

  function testcycle(elem) {
    console.log("cycle");
  }

  function slidecycle(elem) {
    //console.log("slidecycle");
    sliderid = $("#" + elem); //id elementa
    //console.log(sliderid.find(".imgs_holder > .image"));

    var lastimage = sliderid.find(".imgs_holder > .image:last").hasClass("active"); // last image to cycle
    var currentimage = sliderid.find(".imgs_holder > .image.active"); // find current image

    // Check if last image, else use next()
    if (lastimage) {
      var nextimage = sliderid.find(".image_thumb > .image:first")
    } else {
      var nextimage = sliderid.find(".imgs_holder > .image.active").next();
    }

    // Switch active image from current to next()
    $(currentimage).removeClass("active");
    $(nextimage).addClass("active");

    // Duplicate code for animation
    var imgAlt = $(nextimage).find('img').attr("alt");
    var imgSrc = $(nextimage).find('img').attr("src");
    var imgTitle = $(nextimage).find('a').attr("href");
    var imgDesc = $(nextimage).find('.desc').html();
    var imgDescHeight = sliderid.find(".main_image").find('.main-desc').height();

    console.log(nextimage);

    $(nextimage).css("background-color", "#efefef");

    //Switch image 
    sliderid.find(".main_image .main-desc").animate({
      opacity: 0,
      marginBottom: -imgDescHeight
    }, 250, function() {
      sliderid.find(".main_image .main-desc").html(imgDesc).animate({
        opacity: 0.85,
        marginBottom: "0"
      }, 250);
      sliderid.find(".main_image img").attr({
        src: imgSrc,
        alt: imgAlt,
        name: imgAlt
      });
    });
  }

  slide("slider1");
  slide("slider2");
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.imgs_holder {
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  width: auto;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  line-height: 150px;
  padding: auto;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

.image a>img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.main-desc {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  top: 65%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 873px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .7;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}

.main_image {
  position: relative;
  width: 893px;
}

.main_image img {
  width: 893px;
}

.desc {
  display: none;
}

.slideshow {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slideshow" id="slider1">
  <div class="main_image">
    <img src="images/banner01.jpg" alt="slika 1" name="slika 1">
    <div class="main-desc">
      <h3>Subject</h3>
      <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgs_holder">
    <div class="image active">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/banner01.jpg" alt="Slika 1" name="Slika 1" /></a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Subject</h3>
        <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/banner02.jpg" alt="Slika 2" name="Slika 2" /></a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Subject</h3>
        <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/banner03.jpg" alt="Slika 3" name="Slika 3" /></a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Subject</h3>
        <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/banner04.jpg" alt="Slika 4" name="Slika 4" /></a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Subject</h3>
        <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="slideshow" id="slider2">
  <div class="main_image">
    <img src="images/banner01.jpg" alt="slika 1" name="slika 1">
    <div class="main-desc">
      <h3>Subject</h3>
      <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgs_holder">
    <div class="image">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/banner01.jpg" alt="Slika 1" name="Slika 1" /></a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Subject</h3>
        <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/banner02.jpg" alt="Slika 2" name="Slika 2" /></a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Subject</h3>
        <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/banner03.jpg" alt="Slika 3" name="Slika 3" /></a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Subject</h3>
        <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/banner04.jpg" alt="Slika 4" name="Slika 4" /></a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Subject</h3>
        <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can I ask why so many dislikes? There is no topic that solves that problem. There is no topic with working example, etc ... Why negative feedback? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because questions "Why isn't my code working" are not welcome on SO

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of errors in your code.

**Firstly** I reccommend naming jQuery variables with dollar sign at the begining `$`. Eg. `var $test = $(".test");`
That way you won't do unnecessary jQuery call, like in your case

```js
...
var nextimage = sliderid.find(".image_thumb > .image:first");
...
var imgAlt = $(nextimage).find('img').attr("alt");
...
```

`nextimage` variable is already an jQuery object so `$()` is unnecessary.

**Secondly**, you check your current element as an element with class `active` and next element as next element after current. But what if there is no element with class `active` at the begining like in your case in second slider?

You should take that under consideration.

**Thirdly**, when you call `setInterval` function you should do it like this

```
setInterval(function() {
    slidecycle(elem);
}, 4500);
```

**Last but not least** try to elminate jQuery calls to minimum as it is time and memory consuming. Do not repeat yourself - if for example you do some action for the same element mopre than one time, save that element to variable.

Example:

```js
sliderid.find(".main_image").on("mouseover", function() {
  //alert("hover");
  $(this).find(".main-desc").css("display", "block");
});

sliderid.find(".main_image").on("mouseleave", function() {
  //alert("hover");
  $(this).find(".main-desc").css("display", "none");
});
```

To

```js
var $main = sliderid.find(".main_image"),
    $mainDesc = $(this).find(".main-desc");

$main.on("mouseover", function() {
  //alert("hover");
  $mainDesc.css("display", "block");
});

$main.on("mouseleave", function() {
  //alert("hover");
  $mainDesc.css("display", "none");
});
```

Or

```js
var $mainDesc = $(this).find(".main-desc");

sliderid.find(".main_image").on("mouseover", function() {
    //alert("hover");
    $mainDesc.css("display", "block");
  })
  .on("mouseleave", function() {
    //alert("hover");
    $mainDesc.css("display", "none");
  });
```

**Here is an working example:**

```js
var intervalid = {};

$(document).ready(function() {

  function slide(elem) {
    var $slider = $("#" + elem);
    var $description = $slider.find(".main-desc");

    $slider.find(".main_image").on("mouseover", function() {
        $description.show();
      })
      .on("mouseleave", function() {
        $description.hide();
      });

    intervalid[elem] = setInterval(function() {
      slidecycle($slider)
    }, 2000);
  }

  function slidecycle($slider) {

    var lastimage = $slider.find(".imgs_holder .image:last").hasClass("active");
    var $currentImage = $slider.find(".imgs_holder .image.active");

    if ($currentImage.length <= 0) {
      $currentImage = $slider.find(".imgs_holder .image:last");
      lastimage = true;
    }

    if (lastimage) {
      var $nextimage = $slider.find(".imgs_holder .image:first");
    } else {
      var $nextimage = $currentImage.next();
    }

    $currentImage.removeClass("active");
    $nextimage.addClass("active");


    var imgAlt = $nextimage.find('img').attr("alt");
    var imgSrc = $nextimage.find('img').attr("src");
    var imgTitle = $nextimage.find('a').attr("href");
    var imgDesc = $nextimage.find('.desc').html();
    var imgDescHeight = $slider.find(".main_image").find('.main-desc').height();

    $slider.find(".main_image .main-desc").animate({
      opacity: 0,
      marginBottom: -imgDescHeight
    }, 250, function() {
      $slider.find(".main_image .main-desc").html(imgDesc).animate({
        opacity: 0.85,
        marginBottom: "0"
      }, 250);
      $slider.find(".main_image img").attr({
        src: imgSrc,
        alt: imgAlt,
        name: imgAlt
      });
    });
  }

  slide("slider1");
  slide("slider2");
});
```

```css
html {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.imgs_holder {
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  width: auto;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
  line-height: 150px;
  padding: auto;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

.image.active {
  background-color: #efefef
}

.image a>img {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.main-desc {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  top: 65%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 873px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: .7;
  color: white;
  display: none;
}

.main_image {
  position: relative;
  width: 893px;
}

.main_image img {
  width: 893px;
}

.desc {
  display: none;
}

.slideshow {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slideshow" id="slider1">
  <div class="main_image">
    <img src="images/banner01.jpg" alt="Slika 1" name="Slika 1">
    <div class="main-desc">
      <h3>Subject 1</h3>
      <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgs_holder">
    <div class="image active">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/banner01.jpg" alt="Slika 1" name="Slika 1"></a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Subject 1</h3>
        <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/banner02.jpg" alt="Slika 2" name="Slika 2"></a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Subject 2</h3>
        <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/banner03.jpg" alt="Slika 3" name="Slika 3"></a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Subject 3</h3>
        <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/banner04.jpg" alt="Slika 4" name="Slika 4"></a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Subject 4</h3>
        <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slideshow" id="slider2">
  <div class="main_image">
    <img src="images/banner01.jpg" alt="slika 1" name="slika 1">
    <div class="main-desc">
      <h3>Subject</h3>
      <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="imgs_holder">
    <div class="image">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/banner01.jpg" alt="Slika 1" name="Slika 1"></a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Subject</h3>
        <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/banner02.jpg" alt="Slika 2" name="Slika 2"></a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Subject</h3>
        <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/banner03.jpg" alt="Slika 3" name="Slika 3"></a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Subject</h3>
        <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/banner04.jpg" alt="Slika 4" name="Slika 4"></a>
      <div class="desc">
        <h3>Subject</h3>
        <p>Aje, sem desc.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks man for the very detailed answer. Meanwhile, I figred it out, and it's working like a charm now. I came across the same solution or very similar. Special thanks for optimization tricks. Appretiate it really much. Tywm, Krisztof.